# What is the origin of '.' meaning the current directory?

Tags: command-line, syntax, history

*In what OS* did the use of the '.' first mean 'the current directory' ?

Comment: does this sort of question really belong here? What about google?

Comment: No offence, but I can't understand how this question has been voted up 5 times?

Comment: Why should it be Community Wiki?  This kind of thing has an answer, I hope.

Comment: @Mitch: People attempting to get a Civic duty badge? probably :)

Comment: exactly, this is not a opinion answer, why should it be a wiki?  As for googling, you try searching for '.' on google, let me know how that goes.

Comment: Hey, I can think of loads more like this one: "What's the origin of using a backslash as a directory separator?" etc. ... ! :)

Comment: possibly the up votes are purely to frustrate those who are vocal about their belief that the question should not be up voted.

Comment: at least 10 up voters would probably be interested in finding out that answer, mitch :)

Comment: However, in what way does this relate to programming?  Voting to move to SU.

Comment: @Mitch Actually, talking of origins, Unix was using a forward slash and then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589930/so-what-is-the-right-direction-of-the-paths-slash-or/1590078#1590078

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would guess dot = point = current target. but that's just my guess.

Comment: provisionally accepted since as speculative answers go, it's dandy

Comment: How does this answer the question (which is *In what OS did the use of the '.' first mean 'the current directory' ?*)?

Answer (score 3):

> In what OS did the use of the '.' first mean 'the current directory' ?

<strike>I think it was Unix (still trying to find the reference)</strike> Actually, it might be [Multics](http://www.multicians.org/features.html) (a project started in 1964), the first operating system to provide a hierarchical file system:

> I think that Multics was the first to provide a hierarchical file system. The influence of that innovation can be found in virtually every modern operating system, including Unix, Mac OS, DOS and Windows. [[JHS](http://www.multicians.org/multicians.html#Saltzer)]

But I'm still trying to find the reference for the *one period* and *two periods* pointers.

Comment: It is mentioned in the Unix Programmer's Manual version 1 in the manual page for ls.

Comment: @starblue Thank you very much! I'm going to check this right now.

Comment: @starblue Hmmm... Actually, I couldn't find it in the man of ls (Commands, part 2) at http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/1stEdman.html. Are you sure of this? Am I looking at the wrong document?

Answer (score 0):

I believe its because '..' meant one directory up, so '.' was used for the current directory, which explicitly states to only look in the current directory, rather than the path.

Comment: How do you know it wasn't the other way around?

Comment: I don't, I was just speculating.

Answer (score 0):

Being the current point of reference?