# Is it ok to use forward slashes instead of File.separator in my (Gradle) build files?

Tags: java, gradle

I don't see any obvious problems, but I'm wondering if it's ok to use `/` rather than `File.separator` when I'm writing my build files.  Using `File.separator` makes it very difficult to read some of the paths.  Ex:

```java
dependsDir = "${buildDir}${File.separator}depends"
```

vs

```java
dependsDir = "${buildDir}/depends"
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The forward slash (/) is a legal [path separator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29) on Windows, as well as Unix (including Linux and Mac OSX). So unless you need the build to run on other operating systems, it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Could you share where you get this information? A link to the official docs would be perfect. Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1589959/1398479

Comment: It is ONLY valid inside gradle and not in commands executed from gradle. using the path separator in the question is needed to correctly execute external commands.

Answer (score 8):

Gradle for the most part just relies on `java.io.File` to do all path related operations, which in turn gracefully handles `/` on both Windows and Linux. So using `/` in Gradle API is unlikely to cause any problems.

I am using `/` in a fairly large project which runs on both Windows and Linux, and so far I hadn't a single problem. Hope this helps.

Comment: What about mac? Did you test it?

Comment: macOS uses `/` as the separator, so it will work fine on Mac.

Answer (score 3):

When required, use the platform-independent constant `File.separator` eg. `${File.separator}`.

Answer (score 1):

in File Class

```
 public static final String separator = "" + separatorChar;
```

where separatorChar is The system-dependent default name-separator character.  This field is
initialized to contain the first character of the value of the system
property `file.separator`.  On UNIX systems the value of this
field is `'/'`; on Microsoft Windows systems it is `'\'`.

 and the separatorChar created from

```
static private FileSystem fs = FileSystem.getFileSystem();
public static final char separatorChar = fs.getSeparator();
```

For you based on your operating system the separator will be changed, while using File.separator.
by using `/` in your code, it won't support for other OS.