# Java URL separator or File.separator

Tags: java

I have checked similar qestions where they suggested to use `String` as a parameter. But that is what I do.

My Code:

```
 uri.lastIndexOf(File.separator)
```

Where `uri` is: `file:/C:/Users/oto@increase.dk/workspace/Maersk_Line_GaTracking/bin/`

Maybe that is because Windows uses back slashes as file separator. But why then, when I retrieve the URI, I am getting forward slashes?

```
String uri = DataRetrieval.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation() + "";
```

Comment: File.separator: Character that separates components of a file path. This is "/" on UNIX and "\" on Windows. Details: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html

Comment: Didn't really help, that is what I know already...

Comment: Detailed answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589930/so-what-is-the-right-direction-of-the-paths-slash-or-under-windows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CodeSource.getLocation()
```

returns an 
[URL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) object.

Separators in URLs are forward slashes.

Answer (score 5):

There's a difference between file names and URIs.  File names use `\` as a separator on Windows, but URIs *always* use `/`.

So if you're splitting file names, search for File.Separator, and if you're splitting URIs, search for `'/'`

OH, I should mention:  `/` *also* works as a separator in most windows APIs, so for filenames, it's usually a good idea to map all the forward slashes to File.Separator before you start messing with it.

Comment: In the Windows jvm, filenames are permitted to use either `\\` or '/' as a file name separator, so it isn't safe to split a filename using `File.separator`.

Answer (score 1):

URIs are defined to use `/` as their component separator.