# Background style css not working

Tags: css

The background image for div is not working. I have read through all the solutions that you have aldready given. Please help me.

```
<div class="a" style="background-image:url(/img/meetup/CloudOps%20meetup.jp‌eg);" onclick="return true">
</div>
<div class="b"></div>
```

Comment: We're going to need a bit more info, just from this, my best guess is to try and see if your image actually exists in the directory you've specified

Comment: yes,it is available.<div class="a"  style="background-image:url(/img/meetup/CloudOps%20meetup.jpeg);" onclick="return true">
       <div class="b"></div>@LennartHase

Comment: We're going to need your relevant HTML and CSS, otherwise, there's nothing more we can do. The code you've posted should work, so the problem will be elsewhere within your code. Make sure that your `div` has a height and width set

Comment: html code -<div class="scene" style="background-image:url(CloudOpsmeetup.jpeg);">
      <div class="movie"   onclick="return true">
       <div class="poster"></div>
        <div class="info">
         <header>
          <h1></h1>
          <p>
           </p>
         </header>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>css-.scene {
 width: 460px;
 height: 400px;
 margin: 30px;
 float: left;
 
}
@LennartHase

Comment: Please put the code in your question and read the following links: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: please look at the console (browser debugger). is it returning the "not found" error on that image?

Comment: @RishiDev - Please check out the following link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43996209/why-cant-i-set-a-background-image

Comment: No the image is available@YudiChang

Comment: @RishiDev okay, based of that your code is absolutely fine, which means that the image does not exist at the path you've specified, you can verify this by checking the console as Yudi Chang said, or looking at the network tab in the inspector, the file will return a 404, if it's not found.

Comment: yeah, totally forgot about the network tab. like @Lennart said, open network tab, refresh the page, and check if the image load or not (you can also filter it to "Img" to make it easier to check).

Answer (score 0):

Set the background size :

```
body 
{
background : cover;
background: url("http://quizdoo.com/wp-content/uploads/qc-images/58d2957b47354.jpg"); 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do:

```
<div style="background-image:url(/img/meetup/CloudOps%20meetup.jpeg);"> 

</div>
```

You must specify height and width for the background image to be visible. Hope this helps.

Comment: i am not adding it for full section, just a part(div section).But anyways thank you .