# weird behavior of forward and backward slashes in html

Tags: html

consider this code please. A single backslash worked in img tag but not in button tag:

```
<body>
    <h4>This is Me.</h4>
    <img src='C:\Users\foo\Pictures\Camera Roll\pic1.jpg' height="100px" width="100px" id="myImage">
    <button onclick='document.getElementById("myImage").src="C:\Users\foo\Pictures\Camera Roll\pic2.jpg"'>This is you</button>

</body>
```

When I click on the button, nothing happens. image doesn't change.

Now if I change the backward slash with forward slash in button tag, it works!

```
<button onclick='document.getElementById("myImage").src="C:/Users/foo/Pictures/Camera Roll/pic2.jpg"'>This is you</button>
```

Not able to figure out whats wrong with it.

any clue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [So what IS the right direction of the path's slash (/ or \‌) under Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589930/so-what-is-the-right-direction-of-the-paths-slash-or-under-windows)

Comment: That is JavaScript, not HTML.

Comment: Better to use JQuery for this

Comment: @Quentin No, It's not JavaScript. It's HTML and should JQuery for this.

Comment: To answer your question I will have to ask a question what does the single quote do in the img tag that should tell you that attention to detail is important

Comment: @AndreyKaplun — The problem is in the value of the `onclick` attribute, which is JavaScript. There's no point in involving jQuery in this, it doesn't make anything easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of the `onclick` attribute is JavaScript. In JavaScript, `\` is an escape character and to express a literal `\` you need to escape it (i.e. `\\`).

Since you didn't, the string you end up with is: *C:UsersooPicturesCamera Rollpic2.jpg*

```js
console.log("C:\Users\foo\Pictures\Camera Roll\pic2.jpg");
```

The value of the `src` attribute is not JavaScript. `\` is not an escape character in plain HTML.

Instead of escaping your `\` you can replace it with `/` because:

- URLs use / as a path separator
- Windows uses \ as a path separator
- Web browsers, when dealing with Windows paths, still use URL handling code, so can use either more-or-less interchangeably.

Answer (score 2):

Backslash is an escape character, so whatever you put after a backslash is interpreted differently.

To account for this, put an extra backslash to escape the backslash that you intend to put in the address, i.e replace the single backslash `\` with double backslashes `\\` and it should work fine.

Comment: why a single backslash worked in img tag but not in button tag?

Comment: @KawaiKx In the img tag you've used single quotes ' ', so it is read as a static string with \ as is. In the button tag, you've used backticks ` `, where the \ is read as the escape character and not the \, as variable values and other things are substituted when you use backticks.  
Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @AkashSrivastav — There are no backticks in the question at all.