# Should Server.Transfer() use forward slashes or backslashes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-applications

```
Server.Transfer("~\\Error Pages\\404.aspx");
```

Since ~ returns a path with backslashes

Or:

```
Server.Transfer("~/Error Pages/404.aspx");
```

Seen used and fits the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpserverutility.transfer?view=netframework-4.7.2) ("The URL path") more

I tried and they both work.

*So why am I asking?*

Because if you don't do something the *correct* way, it might work now, but it might fail at some point and then it can be pretty difficult to debug.

Comment: Did you flicked through these 
https://stackoverflow.com/q/38428561/4731319 
https://stackoverflow.com/q/1589930/4731319?

Comment: @gpro I know the difference. However the question is whether I should use paths or url paths. But thanks. I'm now editing the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both work, but using `/` is prefered, as `\` internally gets replace by `/`.

*From the .NET Reference Source:*

[`HttpServerUtility.Transfer`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/httpserverutility.cs,685) calls its [`Execute`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/httpserverutility.cs,334) method which uses
`VirtualPath virtualPath = VirtualPath.Create(path);`

This [`VirtualPath.Create`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/VirtualPath.cs,556) calls [`UrlPath.FixVirtualPathSlashes(virtualPath)`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/Util/UrlPath.cs,319) which replaces `\` with `/`.

```
internal static String FixVirtualPathSlashes(string virtualPath) 
{ 
    // Make sure we don't have any back slashes
    virtualPath = virtualPath.Replace('\\', '/');

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The right way to use is

```
Server.Transfer("~/Error Pages/404.aspx");
```

[Example 1](https://www.dotnetperls.com/server-transfer)

[Example 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms525800(v=vs.90))

Comment: Worth an upvote, so +1. But still, the first is just a 3rd party which might be wrong. As for the second. It's outdated. The [current docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpserverutility.transfer?view=netframework-4.7.2) don't contain an example. I'm not even sure that your link is for the exact same thing. But as I said. +1 nevertheless. Thanks.