# Git how to add submodule without a url?

Tags: angular, git, git-submodules

I want to add my angular folder as a submodule to my main directory. The angular folder is initizlied as a git repository. Also, the angular folder is a local folder with no url, existing only on my windows machine.

First, I successfully initiated git init from within my main repo. Then, I added folder1 successfully with

`git add folder1`

But, when I try

```
git submodule add .\angular\.git\
```

or

```
git submodule add .\angular\
```

I get the error "repo URL: '.\frontend.git' must be absolute or begin with ./|../"

```
main repo
│
└───folder1
│   
└───angular
```

How can I add submodule angular to my main repo directory?

Comment: Seems you're in windows and your file path isn't accepted by git. Check out this answer to understand URI vs filepath in windows - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589930/so-what-is-the-right-direction-of-the-paths-slash-or-under-windows)

Comment: Try using `git bash` and type in `git submodule add ./angular`

Answer (score 0):

As clmno mentioned, filepath was the problem. Flipping the slashes worked.

```
git submodule add ./angular/.git/
```

Apparently had to do with windows using backslashes and unix systems using forwardslashes.

Comment: Note that URLs also use forward slashes. Windows is generally fine with forward slashes internally, too; it's just that instead of `-f` or `--force` style options, DOS used `/f` for its `f`-option-letter, so Windows still treats forward slash as option letters, in some places. This makes it hard to distinguish between `prog /path/to/file` and `prog -p -a -t -h`. Of course on Unix systems it's hard to mention a file whose name starts with `-`, but the trick there is to use `./-file`.