# Issue reading file in Python

Tags: python

I had some problems with my Python code.
My code:

```
import os
logininfo = list()
with open(os.getcwd() + '/login/info.txt', 'r') as f:
     logininfo = f.readlines()
```

But my code isn’t work, so how do I fix that?

Edit: I changed the quote and changed the ‘ to '

Problem 2: After I fix all that look like my computer is freeze now and I can’t even move my mouse. After freeze for a while, the code make my computer ran to BSOD. What happened?

Okay, I think I see what the problem in problem 2 that my file was too big with 50 GB of login information of my server. Thanks you guy for helping me solve the problem 1.

Comment: what do you mean code isn't work, what is the resulting output, full text of Traceback error? That will likely show us all the source of the problem

Comment: why are you using two // ?

Comment: can you add more about the error?

Comment: @Andressa Cabistani
I believe thats the problem.

Comment: Also the string for the `'r'` wasn't using single quotes, it was using this one: `

Comment: if that `‘//login//info.txt’` is the same unicode characters in your code as posted, you should get `SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier` for the, `‘`, curly single quotes are unvalid unicode for python syntax. possibly replace those characters with `'`, `'//login//info.txt', 'r'`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough  and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users. "It doesn't work... please tell me" is not a question we can answer. It's not a question at all, in fact.

Comment: ....full Traceback outputs are usually always helpful in these cases of "so anyone can see the problem,"....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is likely that your `/` (forward slashes) are supposed to be `\` (backslashes). It is also [a good practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944387/why-use-os-path-join-over-string-concatenation) to use [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) when concatenating file paths. Make sure `login\info.txt` does not have a backslash in front of it. I printed the list afterwards to make sure it was working. [Windows file paths](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1589959/17020124) use `\\`.

```
import os
with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'login\info.txt'), 'r') as f:
    logininfo = f.readlines()
print(logininfo)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the wrong thing is that you're using double slashs, when it should be:

```py
import os

with open(os.getcwd() + ‘/login/info.txt’, 'r') as f:
     logininfo = f.readlines()
```

I reproduced the error here, created a file with the same folder structure as yours, and this definitely should work:

```py
In [3]: with open(os.getcwd() + '/login/info.txt', 'r') as f:
   ...:     lines = f.readlines()
   ...:     for line in lines:
   ...:         print(line)
   ...: 
Olá,



deixa eu ver esse erro aqui
```

Comment: I fix that but it still didn’t work!

Comment: did you fix the 'r' too??

Comment: Yeah I fix it just see my problem 2 bro!

Comment: try the changes I added in the edition

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of OS, I would recommend using `pathlib` module to deal with system paths and to decrease ambiguity in OS path handling.
So, regardless of OS, an API would be (including your code):

```py
from pathlib import Path

file_path = Path.cwd() / 'login' / 'info.txt'

with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
    login_info = f.readlines()
```

Get familiar with that module (it's out of the box!) here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html

Comment: `file_path` here is an explanatory variable to increase readability. Remember, code reads from top to bottom, not from left to right.