# Python: Excel file (xlsx) export with variable as the file path, using pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I defined an `.xlsx` file path as the variable `output`:

```
print(output)

r'C:\Users\Kev\Documents\Python code.xlsx'
```

I want to export a pandas dataframe as an .xlxs file, but need to have the file path as the output variable.

I can get the code to work with the file path. I've tried about a dozen ways (copying and/or piecing code together from documentation, stack overflow, blogs, etc.) and getting a variety of errors. None worked. Here is one that worked with the file path:

`df = pd.DataFrame(file_list)`

```
df.to_excel(r'C:\Users\Kev\Documents\Python code.xlsx', index=False)
```

I would want something like:
`df.to_excel(output, index=False)` 
In any form or package, as long as it produces the same xlsx file and won’t need to be edited to change the file path and name (that would be done where the variable `output`  is defined.

I've attempted several iterations on the [XlsxWriter site](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html), the [openpyxl site](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pandas.html), the [pandas site](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html), etc.
(with the appropriate python packages). Working in Jupyter Notebook, Python 3.8.

Any resources, packages, or code that will help me to use a variable in place of a file path for an xlsx export from a pandas dataframe?

**Why** I want it like this is a long story, but basically I'll have several places at the top of the code where myself and other (inexperienced) coders can quickly put file paths in and search for keywords (rather than hunt through code to find where to replace paths). The data itself is file paths that I'll iteratively search through (this is the beginning of a larger project).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to put the path this way

```
output = "C://Users//Kev//Documents//Python code.xlsx"
df.to_excel(output , index=False)
```

Always worked for me

or you can also do like

```
output = "C://Users//Kev//Documents//"
df.to_excel(output +"Python code.xlsx" , index=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

os module would be the most useful here:

```
from os import path
output = path.abspath("your_excel_file.xlsx")
print(output)
```

this will return the current working directory path plus the file name you've put into the abspath function as a parameter. Also for those interested about why some people use backslash "\" and not forwardslash "/" while writing file paths here is a good stackoverflow answer for it [So what IS the right direction of the path's slash (/ or \) under Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589930/so-what-is-the-right-direction-of-the-paths-slash-or-under-windows)

Answer (score 1):

You can use format strings with python3

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"a":"b"}, {"c": "d"})
file_name = "filename.xlsx"
df.to_excel(f"/your/path/to/file/{file_name}", index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that OP's dataframe is `df`, that OP is using Windows and wants to store the file in the Desktop, OP's username is `cowboykevin05`, and the filename that one wants is `0001.xlsx`, one can use [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) as follows

```
from os import path

df.to_excel(path.join('C:\\Users\\cowboykevin05\\Desktop', '0001.xlsx'), index=False)
```